# Purge blobs by default in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Removing an [ActiveStorage](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#removing-files) object in Rails 6 does not purge the blob. It deletes the record form the database but the file still exists. One needs to manually call `purge` or `purge_later` in order to permanently remove the file.

This took me by surprise, why would you want to remove the reference but keep the file?

Is there a way to change the default and tell Rails to always purge the blob/file if the record is removed?

Alternatively I could manually check if any attachments have been removed in an `after_save` hook or have a cronjob to remove all orphaned files periodically. What would be the most idiomatic way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I am using the [Apartment](https://rubygems.org/gems/ros-apartment) gem and forgot to exclude the ActiveStorage models. The Apartment gem uses database views so it would remove the reference from the database but I guess the `purge_later` does not run in the same database scope.

Excluding the ActiveStorage models in the `config/initializers/apartment.rb` did the trick.

```
config.excluded_models = %w{ ActiveStorage::Attachment ActiveStorage::Blob }
```